# value not coming from razor ajax to action method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Id in the action method is always null. lost where i am doing anything wrong. action method is called as expected.

jQuery function:

```
function success(result) {
    var Id = $('#UserId').val();
    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'Id': Id });
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("ListAppointments", "Appointment")",
        data: data,

        success: function (result2) {
            $("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2);
            $('#example').DataTable();

        }
    });
}
```

Action Method:

```
public PartialViewResult ListAppointments(string Id)
{
    var userId = Convert.ToInt32(Id);
    var o = (from s in db.tblAppointments.ToList()
             where s.UserId == userId
             select new AppointmentViewModel { AppointmentInstructorName = s.InstructorName, AppointmentLessonAddress = s.Address, LessonDateTime = s.LessonDate, UserId = s.UserId, Id = s.ID });

    return PartialView(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do `JSON stringify` on your data. You can send the js object as it is.

```
var d ={ Id:  $('#UserId').val()};
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("ListAppointments", "Home")",
            data: d
            success: function (result2) {
              $("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2);
              $('#example').DataTable();
            }
   });
```

Now since this is a GET request the data (the js object) will be send as a querystring values to the server (Ex : `ListAppointments?Id=23`)

So when you do `JSON.stringify` call on that js object, It will return a **string** like `"{"Id":23}"`. So your final url used for the ajax call(with the querystring) will be `ListAppointments?{"Id":23}`. You can see that this is not valid. It should be `ListAppointments?Id=23`

If you still want to use `JSON.stringify` (to send complex data), specify `contentType` and use `POST` method.

Also i see you are converting the string param value to int in your action method, why not use `int` as parameter type since you are sending numeric data ?

```
public PartialViewResult ListAppointments(int Id)
{

}
```

Comment: why wouldn't it work with stringify because that's what i found out?

Comment: I am updating the answer to include that info in 1 mnt

Comment: thankyou. it makes sense. i have marked it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

by doing this way, i have it working. not sure why the stringify function would stop it from working:

```
  function success(result) {
        var Id = $('#UserId').val();
        var data = ({ Id: Id });
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("ListAppointments", "Appointment")",
            data: data,
            success: function (result2) {
                $("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2);
                $('#example').DataTable();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing `Content-Type:'application/json'` but assuming you have left the default route you can just pass it with the query parameter

```
function success(result) {
    var Id = $('#UserId').val();
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("ListAppointments", "Appointment")" + "?id=" + Id,
        data: data,
        success: function (result2) {
            $("#partialViewAppointments").html(result2);
            $('#example').DataTable();

        }
    });
}
```